# How to convert Element into Form?

Tags: elm

How can I convert `Mouse.position` into `Form`, so I can display it in a collage? The following code displays `<Signal>` instead of the actual mouse coordinates:

```
render (x, y) =
    let mousePos = toForm (show Mouse.position)
    in collage 400 400 [mousePos]
```

It's curious that in this example http://elm-lang.org/examples/mouse-position, the `show` function actually transforms `Mouse.position` into a string with coordinates, but that is because the `show` function is used to filter a `Signal(Int, Int)` into a tuple of `Signal` values.

So my question is, how do I convert a `Signal(Int, Int)` into a `Form`, so that it shows the tuple values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for `Graphics.Collage.toForm` which has the type `Element -> Form`.

It also sounds like you don't quite understand what `Signal.map` is doing. It takes a function to be applied to each value of a `Signal`. I've tried to use it in several contexts in the following example.

```
import Graphics.Element exposing (..)
import Graphics.Collage
import Graphics.Collage exposing (Form)
import Mouse

--This is the function you are trying to construct.
--It takes in a position, converts it to an element,
--using show and then converts it to a Form.
formPosition : (Int, Int) -> Form
formPosition pos = 
  let element = show pos -- element : Element 
  in Graphics.Collage.toForm element

-- We now want to apply our formPosition function to the
-- Signal containing all mouse position changes.
-- So we use Signal.map to apply formPosition to all values
-- of Mouse.position
formSignal : Signal Form
formSignal = Signal.map formPosition Mouse.position

-- Eventually we want to render this on the screen and the
-- function to do this requires a List Form not just a single
-- Form. So we write a function which returns a Singleton list
-- and apply it to each value in our formSignal.
formListSignal : Signal (List Form)
formListSignal = Signal.map (\n -> [n]) formSignal


-- Finally, we must turn that into a Signal Element to render
-- on the screen. We partially apply Graphics.Collage.collage
-- to return an element of size 400x400 and apply it to the 
-- values of formListSignal by using Signal.map again
elementSignal : Signal Element
elementSignal = Signal.map (Graphics.Collage.collage 400 400) formListSignal

-- Finally we hand this off to main and it renders
main : Signal Element
main = elementSignal
```

A simpler version would likely combine all of the conversions into a single function. I just wanted to emphasize how `Signal.map` worked. I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! This worked. And, yes, you were right. I didn't quite understand what `Signal.map` was doing.